# Dialogflow CX edition: Restore BLOB file agent error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-cx

I am trying to restore an agent from a .BLOB file, and I get a  "language not supported by platform" error while importing the BLOB file. (screen shot attached)

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance,
Claudia

[image: DialogFlow CX restoring error]

Comment: Can you please detail how did you obtain this .blob file? According to GCP documentation, restore agent only works from previously exported agents and both exported and restored agents are provided as .zip files : https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-settings#export

Comment: Hi Fernando,  you get the .blob file when downloading (or exporting) an agent to your PC from Dialogflow CX plataform. Zip files work only for Dialogflow ES version (until now, at least)

Comment: Could you please confirm what language are you using in your Dialogflow CX agent? Kindly note that "en - English" is currently the only supported language in Dialogflow CX. For reference, please see: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs#limits